# Javascript object value wont change es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, lodash

I have cloned a javascript object using lodash.cloneDeep().
I want to change the value of one of the object properties and just print out for testing purpose. But "this" does not seem to change.

```
const object = {
  id: 'old value',
  toString: () => {
   console.log(this.id);
  },
  getThis: () => {
   return this;
  }
}

const clonedObj = _.cloneDeep(object);

clonedObj.id = 'new value'

console.log(clonedObj.id) // returns "new value"
clonedObj.toString()      // returns "old value"

console.log(cloneObj === object) // returns false
console.log(cloneObj.getThis === object) // returns true
```

Can someone help me understand this.

Comment: clonedObj.toString===object.toString

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to the object. When using ES6-arrow `this` becomes window and not the object.

Comment: ahh, really?? I will try that, thanks!

Comment: @AleksanderAleksic try logging just the `this` in your code. Then change your `=>` to a regular function `function()` and you will see the difference. It doesn't always refer to the window but in this case it does.

Comment: Small correction: `this` within an arrow function refers to the `this` of the surrounding scope. This is often the global scope and thus `this` equals `window` - but not always.

Comment: @ rymdmaskin I did not know this about arrow functions but it really did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: This MDN [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), under the section _Arrow functions used as methods_, describes the issue you are facing.

Comment: it is a constant. how can we change its key's value

Comment: @AbhinavS.Chauhan with const you can change the "content" but not the pointing. So you cant set object = 'something'

Comment: @AleksanderAleksic thnx for telling me that